# Employee clock in - cookie subtracts one from original value

Tags: php, mysql, cookies

I'm in the process of creating an employee time card with a clock in/clock out feature. I have it so when the employee hits the 'clockin' button, the current time and date are sent to the 'timein' column of a mysql database. The unique id of that row is then remembered as a cookie so that when the employee clocks out it will input the current time into the same row as the clock in. The problem is that the id that the cookie stores is always one lower than the id of the clock in row. This can be seen when I echo the id after I insert the current time into the clock in and when I echo the id after I create the cookie. The cookie having the same value as the clock in row id (both are '$id').

The issue might have something to do with the fact that the id column is set to auto increment.

```
<?php
include ("connection.php");
if ($_POST['clockin'] == "Clock In") {  

    $clockin = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $timestamp = "INSERT INTO `timestamp` (`timein`) VALUES ('$clockin')";
    mysqli_query($link,$timestamp);
    $id = mysqli_insert_id($link);
    echo "$id";


    $cookie_name = "timein";
    $cookie_value = $id;
    setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400), "/");  

if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
    echo "Cookie named '" . $cookie_name . "' is not set!";
} else {
    echo "Cookie '" . $cookie_name . "' is set!<br>";
    echo "Value is: " . $_COOKIE[$cookie_name];
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: This is not exactly a robust approach. What if someone uses an anonymous tab in a browser (by accident, for example) or (had to) delete cookies during the day? What if the lockout is done from a different system or browser than the login? Also this allows free manipulation and automation, so employees can actually chose themselves how much the _really_ want to work whilst still having a great and clean timekeeping account.

Comment: you may use simple login system which after a successful login it redirects the employee to a page with two option, `clock in` and `clock out` and when the employee clicks one of them it writes into the database the employee id, the date and the clock in and out times those you capture upon the employee clicks

Comment: What would you suggest as an alternative to using cookies @arkascha?

Comment: @muninn9 I didn't say anything against cookies in general. I don't think they are required these days, since php sessions for example can work without them. But that is not the issue here. The architectural flaw in your design is to rely on a cookie for the specific purpose of identifying an item in your database. An issue because it is an absolutely weak identification, since it is stored outside where it can be manipulated at will. Why do you need that at all? If you know who is logged into your website, then that is enough to identify the database item when that person logs out again.